# Get xml document in Chrome via JS

Tags: javascript, html, xml, google-chrome

After I open an Xml document in Chrome, I want to get the XML source in console via js.

But document object seems to be an HTML document.

So How can I get the real Xml and is there any way to judge whether a file is an xml document?

Comment: How do you open it in Chrome? what do you mean by that?

Comment: Is this question helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6411723/what-is-the-difference-between-html-dom-and-xml-dom

Comment: @Barmar When Chrome browser load an document, I want to know whether it is an XML or HTML, and if XML, I want to get the XML source.

Comment: @GrzegorzKaczan write an xml file, and open it with Chrome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

XML is just data, it's not a representation of a textual or graphical document like HTML is. So when you load an XML document into Chrome, it synthesizes an HTML document that displays the XML DOM as text.

However, it stashes the original XML DOM in an element of the page:

```
<div id="webkit-xml-viewer-source-xml">
    ... XML DOM is here
</div>
```

So if `document.getElementById("webkit-xml-viewer-source-xml")` returns an element, the document was originally XML. You can then use this element's `.innerHTML` property to get the XML as text.