# How to style an XML fragment with Greasemonkey?

Tags: javascript, css, xml, xslt, greasemonkey

I am trying to style XML fragment from a server response with a Greasemonkey script.

[Example XML fragment from w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml):

```
<note>
  <to> Tove</to>
  <from>Jani</from>
  <heading>Reminder</heading>
  <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

(It has no declaration on top like `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`)

Firefox reports:

> This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated
>   with it. The document tree is shown below.

How can I style the display?
Can I convert it to proper HTML? How?

**N.B.** I can grab and parse the data using XHR but I am trying to avoid XHR and use the browser to display the data (since it is a GET method). All I need is to format it to a more readable format.

Comment: Show us the AJAX-call

Comment: Wouldn't _not_ declaring the type be invalid? I'm no XML expert, but I just though that was something you're supposed to do.

Comment: @PeteTNT: I am trying to avoid using XHR, otherwise I can parse it.
Xero: This is a server output, not a proper page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You "style" XML using [*Extensible Stylesheet Language Transformations* (XSLT)](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt/info). XSLT parses XML into HTML using stylesheets.  You can then use standard CSS to format the display of the resulting HTML.

For [the sample XML you cited](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml), this stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="html"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <xsl:for-each select="note">
                    <p> <xsl:value-of select="body"/> </p>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

would give you a properly formed HTML document that just listed the `note` body.  EG: `Don't forget me this weekend!` from your example.

---

Use `XSLTProcessor()` to run XSLT in a Greasemonkey script, like so:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        _XML renderer / styler
// @description stylesheet for xml results
// @include     http://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*.xml
// @include     http://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

//-- Warning, multiline str is new in JS. Only Firefox supports at the moment.
var xsl_str = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="html"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>My super new note format!</title>
                <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
                <style type="text/css">
                    body { padding: 0 2em; }
                    .noteCtr {
                        border: 1px solid gray;
                        border-radius: 1ex;
                        padding: 0;
                        background: #FAFAFA;
                    }
                    .messPeople { font-size: 1em; margin: 1ex 1em; }
                    .messHeading { background: lightcyan; margin: 0 1.6ex; }
                    .messHeading::after { content: ":"; }
                    .noteCtr > p {
                        background: white;
                        padding: 1em;
                        margin: 0 1em 1.5ex 1em;
                    }
                </style>
            </head>
            <body>
                <xsl:for-each select="note">
                    <div class="noteCtr">
                        <h3 class="messPeople">
                            <xsl:value-of select="from"/>
                            --&gt;
                            <xsl:value-of select="to"/>
                        </h3>
                        <h3 class="messHeading"> <xsl:value-of select="heading"/> </h3>
                        <p> <xsl:value-of select="body"/> </p>
                    </div>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
`;

var processor   = new XSLTProcessor ();
var dataXSL     = new DOMParser ().parseFromString (xsl_str, "text/xml");

processor.importStylesheet (dataXSL);

var newDoc      = processor.transformToDocument (document);

//-- These next lines swap the new, processed doc in for the old one...
window.content  = newDoc;

document.replaceChild (
    document.importNode (newDoc.documentElement, true),
    document.documentElement
);
```

Here I stored the stylesheet in the `xsl_str` variable.  For more involved operations, you may find it better to [fetch the stylesheet via a `@resource` directive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18050809/331508).

### Install that script and then visit [your example XML](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml).

You will see it transform that document...

## From:

[image: Before XSLT]

## To:

[image: After XSLT]

Comment: you don't actually need to use XSLT to style XML, you can also apply a CSS stylesheet by using a xml stylesheet processing node, see http://www.w3.org/Style/styling-XML.en.html

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in Chrome (not because of missing `\`` support, but because the `body` in `newContent` isn't populated), while the code works in Firefox, I can't get this loaded when using ViolentMonkey

Comment: As follow-up, in webkit browers this seems related to the XML pretty printer (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16729263/get-xml-document-in-chrome-via-js) and so instead of `document` something like the result of `new DOMParser().parseFromString(document.getElementById('webkit-xml-viewer-source-xml').innerHTML, 'text/xml');` should be used

Comment: @Treviño, a lot has changed in 4.5 years and the [greasemonkey] tag implies Firefox-only (as apposed to the [tampermonkey] or [userscripts] tags). Open a new question if you need to.

Comment: FYI, Tampermonkey works fine (in firefox at least).

Comment: @Treviño, so you say that on Firefox, the script works on Tampermonkey but not Violentmonkey?  If so, that may be due to Violentmonkey's `@inject-into` setting.  But I don't have time to look into this right now.