# Script onload in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have script, which appends in the document:

```
window.d = document     

s = d.createElement('script') 
s.setAttribute('type','text/javascript')
s.setAttribute('src',options.url)
d.getElementById(block_id).appendChild(s)

$(s).load(function() { 
    alert('')
})
```

In Opera, FF and Chrome `load` works fine, but not in IE.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this similar question may help you

[Element.appendChild() chokes in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436710/element-appendchild-chokes-in-ie)

The reason may be that `appendChild` just doesn't work in IE.

Comment: My IE never choked in the application I made similar to google calendar.As far as I remember, IE engine needs those (;)s. Happened with me once. WebKit based browsers fix them on their own ;)