# jquery function works in the firebug console but not in the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following jquery function

```
$("#photographers_password_confirm").focusout(function() { 
alert('bla') 
if( $("#photographers_password") != $("photographers_password_confirm") ){
                    $("#photographers_password_error").slideDown();
            }else{
                    $("#photographers_password_error").hide();
            }   
});
```

it works fine in the firebug console but when I put it in the page it fails to work but it also doesnt return any error in the firebug console. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you put your code along with some relevant markup on [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)? It is difficult to figure out from just the above code.

Comment: Are you wrapping it in `$(document).ready()`? If you're adding `#photographers_password_confirm`, you need to use `$("#photographers_password_confirm").live('focusout', function () {})` instead.

Comment: you want to compare the fields values, not jQuery objects:  $("#photographers_password").val()   $("photographers_password_confirm").val()

Answer (score 1):

in the page, are you running it "inline", as part of the HTML download, or are you running it after the document has completed its download?

my guess is that the code is running alright, but it's running before the HTML is ready to be manipulated.

make sure it's in a `$(function() { /* place code here */ });` block

Comment: thanks alot, that works ... but now for some reason the function isnt acting like its suppose to.... any idea why

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$("#photographers_password_error").slideUp();
$("#photographers_password_confirm").focusout(function() {
    alert('bla');
    if ($("#photographers_password").val() != $("#photographers_password_confirm").val()) {
        $("#photographers_password_error").slideDown();
    } else {
        $("#photographers_password_error").slideUp();
    }
});
```

Answer (score -2):

If this is the exact code, then please put a `;` after the alert. Some browsers take it and some don't so it would be nice to follow the same old coding style :)

Comment: `Some browsers take it and some don't`... any examples? This is ridiculous AFAIK.

Comment: Here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8091606/script-onload-in-ie/8091646#8091646

Comment: Urr, that's a link to one of your own answers... with no evidence that  `Some browsers take it and some don't`. Semi-colons is optional in JavaScript, and it's recommended you put them in yourself; but because things like `return \n 3 +4` will return undefined, not 7... not because the result is inconsistent across browsers.

Comment: Some more people think this way: http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum91/521.htm and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8119532/does-a-semi-colon-matter-in-javascript/8119580#8119580 .. I just asked that question to be sure that it was not only me who had that issue.. And by the way, that answer of mine worked for him. Strange, but true :)

Comment: Rohan: If you take out the semi-colon you added to *fix* the code, I bet it'd still work. If not, please post a code example.

Comment: Matt: Here is a jsfiddle someone created as an answer to my question. http://jsfiddle.net/zZcUx/1/ . By the way, I had the same argument with one of my friends over this. :)

Comment: Rohan: What do you mean **that answer of mine worked for him**? That code snippet doesn't apply here. The *problem* in that JS Fiddle is that the `return` and the `{}` is on separate lines... that doesn't apply here.

Comment: Kindly go through "JavaScript: The Good Parts" Appendix A.3. The author clearly mentions what I am saying. In the 2nd link of my previous comment, someone mentioned about the strict behavior of some broswers while interpreting JavaScript.

Comment: I've read the book, but I don't remember **anyone** saying `Some browsers take it and some don't`

Comment: My question to you: Who adds the missing semi-colons, in case they are not present? :) Most authors never take browsers into consideration. They take the language standards.

Comment: Do all browsers have the same interpreter? If no, then isn't it a browser issue in the end? :)

Comment: @Rohan: Of course they don't, but they all adhere to [the standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf) (AFAIK; which was what I was asking), which describes how semi-colon insertion should occur. As they **all** apply the standard, your statement (and whole answer) `Some browsers take it and some don't` is rubbish.

Comment: @Dori: That's the short way of saying it ;)