# Creating and populating <style> elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

Firefox and Chrome let me create a `<style>` element and populate it, all from JavaScript. I could swear that in the past I've done that in IE (like, IE6), in different circumstances. But now I can't get IE (7 or 8; haven't tried 9) to let me set it at all.

I have this recollection of a "cssText" property, but now in the (mysteriously diminished; does anybody know what happened to the MSDN documentation site?) MSDN docs that only shows up as a part of the stylesheet API and not as a DOM element thing.

So: is it at all possible to create and populate a `<style>` element in Internet Explorer?

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/3skkD/) is a trivial jsfiddle example, with the following jQuery code:

```
$('head').append($('<style/>', { html: 'div { color: red; }' }));
```

Works fine in Firefox, Chrome, and Opera. (I guess I should try Android and iOS while I'm at it.)

*edit* — yes, I've tried setting "text" instead of "html", and it doesn't help. Trying to set "innerText" without jQuery also doesn't work.

Comment: Were you looking for this method: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/436710/element-appendchild-chokes-in-ie?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how I've done this before. I've pretty much copied this straight out of some old code of mine, but if I remember correctly, the `styleSheet` property is only used by IE, and as you mentioned, that's when you need to use `cssText`:

```
var styleElem = document.createElement("style");
styleElem.type = "text/css";
styleRules = document.createTextNode(".someClass { color: red; }");
if(styleElem.styleSheet) {
    styleElem.styleSheet.cssText = styleRules.nodeValue;
}
else {
    styleElem.appendChild(styleRules);
}
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(styleElem);​
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/esDNG/1/) (tested in latest Chrome and IE6).

Comment: Yes I think that's right; doh.  I'll give it a try and accept in a sec.

Comment: Oh, and I think I'll log a jQuery bug, since it really should let me do this somehow.

Comment: @Pointy - Yeah, seeing as jQuery is designed to normalise browser inconsistencies I think this would be a useful addition.

Comment: Oh yeah. And like you mentioned in your question, I can't find much info at all on the `cssText` property, or the `styleSheet` property. Strange.

Comment: The MSDN documentation *used to be* somewhat useful, if a little stuffy. Some time recently somebody went through it with a weed whacker or something. It's weird.